# Firebase functions not serving static files with express.js and EJS view engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, ejs

I've been researching over this issue for the past month and I am not finding any useful solutions. I am currently trying to host a website using the firebase functions, along with express.js and the EJS view engine.

I'm going into the issue of serving static CSS files into the EJS files. I've looked all over but can't seem to find any proper answer that helps.

I have the following file structure (inside the functions folder):

- public
- views
- index.js

Here's my index.js:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
var path = require('path');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.render("test");
})

// app.listen(5000, () => {
    // console.log("Active app on port 5000");
// });
exports.webApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The page it is rendering (test.ejs):

```js
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>


<body></body>
</html>
```

And finally, the style.css file:

```js
html {
    background-color: black;
}
```

(The style.css is done like that along with the test.ejs only for testing as I was having a big issue with all of this)

I tried most of the solutions online, however all of them only work while running the express.js app locally and **not** through the firebase serve or deploy commands. I am totally lost in regards to this and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m seeing this issue with Cloud Run and express static middleware. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Would mind sharing your folder structure? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I don't think @zemunkh's answer is correct.

Comment: anyone who came across this issue, please see my question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68346542?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

**The TL;DR of the issue:**

In normal NodeJS & Express hosting one needs to specify the directory of your static content. Since firebase hosting does this static content hosting for you (where the `/public` directory is hosted at your domain root),

**Solution:** you can do the following:

1. simply omit the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` (as this removes the *duplicate* hosting attempt that firebase hosting is doing for you)
2. all your styles, javascript, etc needs to omit the `/public` portion,

**For example**

**from** this:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/public/styles/my-styles.css")
```

**to** this:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/styles/my-styles.css")
```

You can test this:

1. Host your app with the original (faulty/incorrect static resource links), then browse to the static resource link - you should get a 404 or failure to load resource atleast.
2. Using the same "faulty" link, omit the ".../public..." portion of the url, your static content will render correctly.

This means firebase hosting is hosting all the content of the `/public` directory to the root of your domain.

3. Next, make the change by removing the static directory `app.use()` function and remove all traces of `/public` in your static content links (as shown above).
4. Browse to your page (that includes the altered static routes), your page will load correctly with all your styles, scripts, etc (assuming you don't have any faulty code ;) )

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is because of the Google Cloud Plan.

In the beginning, all firebase users go with the Spark plan, which is completely free. In recently, **Google Cloud** may have blocked some features that we used free a year ago.

So, You need to go to [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/projects), then change the plan of your project you want to deploy. Then if you didn't register your payment card, you should do that for the **firebase hosting** or **firebase functions** feature.
[image]

A few minutes later, it loads all necessary files, such as a styling CSS, JS files that were missing when loading your deployed website.

Then enjoy your deployed website. ;)

Comment: I hope this is it! I'm having the exact same issue! I can serve my static files no problem on localhost, but then don't load on Firebase hosting. I just updated my billing account to the project (5 minutes ago), but it's still not working. Fingers crossed it will work soon :)

Comment: That's weird. I have plans always set to Blaze but it's not working. Would you mind sharing your code to me (not the whole thing of course)? I wanna see the structure of files and how you are setting up the server. Thank you.

Comment: Yeap, directory in the host app of firebase is a kind of intriguing. You should check this tutorial. It worked for me as I remember. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem in July 2021.
the firebase cloud function is not available for the Spark(free) plan.
You need to upgrade your project to a Blaze plan first (Worry not! This is Pay as you go plan. the spark plan is included in it, So you will be not charged until you exceed the limit).
To upgrade to the blaze plan you need to set up billing information in the Google Cloud platform which will be directed automatically when you opt for the upgrade.

Here is my code for EJS View engine setup in firebase function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');                                
    const express = require("express");         
    const app = express();


    app.set("views",__dirname+"/tmp");
    app.set("view engine","pug");
    app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express);
    app.get("/",p3p(p3p.recommended),function(req,res){
       res.render("index");
    });
    app.get("/login",p3p(p3p.recommended),function(req,res){
       res.render("login");
    });
    exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I hope you can relate it to the pug view engine and configure your setup in the firebase function for serving the static files.